# React Native - setNativeProps() on parentElement.props.children = undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm developing a school management app for myself.
All students in my class are listed in a Flatlist with their parents' phone numbers beside to enable me to send them text messages when a student is absent.

I have a *FlatList* with Listitems, each of which contains a Touchopacity component with *Text* child inside.

On successful sending an sms to a student's parent (smsParent method) I want to setNativeProps on both *TouchOpacity* and its *Text* child (manipulate their style props). I use ref=(()=>...) to have reference to *Touchopacity* and then **this.props.children** *(only 1 child)* to get to its *Text* child.

Then however I cannot use setNativeProps (=undefined). 
However, when I use ref=(()=>...) on *Text* as well and then refer to it, setNativeProps works /like in case of its parent/.

**Why can't I use setNativeProps() on a child when refering to it by parentEl.props.children?** (only 1 child, checked in debugger, it's properly identified)

Please read comments in smsParent method

/*sorry for inserting a snippet - code insertion was crazily formatted/

/**code simplified/

```js
class SingleClassPage extends Component {

  buttons = new Array();

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { students: [] };
    this.smsParent = this.smsParent.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    //fetch students from api and setState..
    this._getStudentsList();
  }

  _getStudentsList() {
    // ...
  }

  //flatlist item
  ListEl(props) {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity ref={el => { let a = props.item.attId + 'att'; props.buttons[a] = el; }}
          style={[styles.buttonDef, (props.item.phone_parent ? styles.buttonBlue : styles.buttonGray)]}
          onPress={() => { props.smsSendHandler(props.item, 'attendance', a) }}>
          <Text style={props.item.phone_parent ? styles.buttonTextLight : styles.buttonTextDark}>
            {props.item.smsAttSent ? 'sms sent' : 'sms send'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.students}
          extraData={this.state}
          keyExtractor={item => item.attId}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <this.ListEl buttons={this.buttons} item={item} smsSendHandler={this.smsParent} />}
        />
        <BusyIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }


  smsParent(student, msgCategory, smsButton) {

    //call myjava module and upon successful callback call below:

    let parEl = this.buttons[smsButton];
    //childEl is an object with props.children set to text 'sms sent/send' when I watch its value in debugger
    //so it's correctly identified
    let childEl = parEl.props.children;

    // WORKS 
    parEl.setNativeProps({ style: { backgroundColor: 'green' } });
    // OOPS
    childEl.setNativeProps({ style: { color: 'black' } });
  }
}
```

edit1
Posting a screenshot of the error (also as response to Dyo's suggestion below - the same error Dyo...)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to iterate throught children to pass them nativeProps (even if there's only one child) :

```
smsParent(student, msgCategory, smsButton) {

    //call myjava module and upon successful callback call below:

    let parEl = this.buttons[smsButton];

    React.Children.forEach(parEl.props.children, child => { child.setNativeProps({ style: { color: 'black' } }) });

    parEl.setNativeProps({ style: { backgroundColor: 'green' } });

  }
```

Comment: Dyo I wanted to post a screenshot. Since I cannot do it in comments, I edited the qs.